# Como agrupar solo algunas barras en pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Tengo los siguientes datos den un DataFrame de Pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

news = [0,1669,956,125]
total = [7836,8133,7905,2374]
perdidos = [0,1372,1184,0]
years = [2017,2018,2019,2020]

df = pd.DataFrame('Nuevos':news, 'Totales': total, 'Perdidos':perdidos)
```

Quiero representar los valores de Totales y Nuevos superpuestos (stacked) y los valores de perdidos como una barra roja al lado de la barra acumulada de nuevos y totales.
Hasta ahora he probado lo siguiente:

```py
plt.style.use('seaborn')

df = pd.DataFrame({'Nuevos':news,'Total':total})
perdidos = pd.DataFrame({'Perdidos': perdidos})

ax = df.plot.bar(rot = 0, stacked = True)
ax.plot.bar(perdidos)
ax.set_xticklabels(years)
ax.set_ylabel('Clientes', fontsize = 14)
ax.set_xlabel('Año', fontsize = 14)
ax.set_title("Clientes Anuales %s" % titulos[var_almacen], fontsize = 16);
```

Pero el resultado son dos gráficas separadas, la acumulada con el fomato deseado y al otra como un grafico de barras a parte:
[image: Grafico]

[image: grafico2]

¿Cómo podría unificarlo en un solo gráfico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes resolver si haces lo siguiente:

- Pasas a la segunda llamada a `pandas.DataFrame.plot` mediante el argumento `ax`el eje retornado por la anterior llamada. De ésta forma ambos gráficos usaran el mismo eje y la misma figura.
- Usas conjuntamente los argumentos `align` y `width` para alinear cada barra sobre un borde distinto. La idea es alinear la barras teniendo en cuenta sus bordes y no su centro, `align="edge"`, la primera la alineamos usando su borde derecho y la segunda su borde izquierdo, de forma que quedan una al lado de la otra y una a cada lado del valor del eje <kbd>x</kbd> que les corresponde. Además debes darse solo parte del ancho inicial para que no se junten las parejas dado que ahora dos barras deben compartir el espacio de una. Al final hay una explicación detallada de como funcionan ambos parámetros conjuntamente.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

news = [0,1669,956,125]
total = [7836,8133,7905,2374]
perdidos = [0,1372,1184,0]
years = [2017,2018,2019,2020]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Nuevos':news,'Total':total})
perdidos = pd.DataFrame({'Perdidos': perdidos})

plt.style.use('seaborn')
ax = df.plot(kind="bar", width=-0.4, rot=0, stacked=True, align='edge')
perdidos.plot(ax=ax, width=0.4, kind="bar",align='edge', color="red")
ax.set_xticklabels(years)
ax.set_ylabel('Clientes', fontsize = 14)
ax.set_xlabel('Año', fontsize = 14)
#ax.set_title("Clientes Anuales %s" % titulos[var_almacen], fontsize = 16)
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x')
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### **Los argumentos aling y width**

El argumento `align` por defecto es `"center"`, ésto indica que el centro de la barra debe alinearse con el valor del eje, en éste caso, barras verticales, el eje <kbd>x</kbd>.

Su otro valor posible es `"edge"` (vértice), en éste caso no se alinea con el valor del eje el centro de la barra, sino el borde. el borde que se alinea depende de si `width` es positivo o negativo:

- **`align = "center"`**

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  df = pd.DataFrame({"Data": [3, 5, 7, 11, 13]})
  df.plot(kind="bar", align="center")
  plt.show()
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- **`align = "edge"` y `width` positiva**

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  df = pd.DataFrame({"Data": [3, 5, 7, 11, 13]})
  df.plot(kind="bar", align="edge", width=0.5)
  plt.show()
  ```

  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- **`align = "edge"` y `width` negativa**

  ```
  import pandas as pd
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  df = pd.DataFrame({"Data": [3, 5, 7, 11, 13]})
  df.plot(kind="bar", align="edge", width=-0.5)
  plt.show()
  ```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Osea que lo que haces es primero crear un plot en ax, el cual desplazas del centro para posteriormente hacer lo mismo con los datos siguientes pero desplazandolos por cada barra en sentido contrario? Es por eso que empleas el align = 'edge', ¿ para que tome el centro de las barras como "centro"?

Comment: Hola, he editado la respuesta, creo que no deje nada claro el punto que señalas. Al final explico como funciona los argumento align y with conjuntamente y por qué en este caso nos solventan el problema.